# John Conway and 15·92

Tags: recreational-mathematics, math-history, mathematicians

The Economist featured an obituary of John Conway (https://www.economist.com/obituary/2020/04/23/john-conway-died-on-april-11th, may be paywalled) which includes a photograph of him in what I guess is his office at Princeton in the late 80's. On top of his computer monitor is a card with the number 15·92; what does this mean? The use of a "middle-dot" suggests that it is not a decimal number, and it is not a date or time in a commonly-used format. I am aware that Conway was not a "common-user" (as a date it is May 31 of the following year, as a time 28 minutes before five), but why did he find this number sufficiently important to dominate his work environment?

Comment: Your question should fit better on [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @YuiTo Cheng I did wonder which SE to use but I found more references to Conway here than on HSM. Lacking a better criterion, I posted here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That was his personal record (at the time)  for a running computational challenge.  Specifically, the challenge was:  a computer would generate $10$ dates randomly from the past few hundred years and one had to provide all $10$ days of the week.  He did it in $15.92$ seconds.  ( Later he was able to get it under $10$ seconds).

See [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2015/jul/23/john-horton-conway-the-most-charismatic-mathematician-in-the-world) for a reference.